# Liquibase Change Log Parameter error: ERROR: syntax error at or near "$"

Tags: liquibase

I have a changelog:

```
   <sql>
        DROP ROLE IF EXISTS tenant_access;

        CREATE ROLE tenant_access
        NOSUPERUSER INHERIT NOCREATEDB
        NOCREATEROLE NOREPLICATION;

        GRANT ALL ON DATABASE ${db_name} TO tenant_access;
    </sql>
```

And in the liquibase.properties I have:

```
changeLogFile=src/main/resources/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.xml
url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres
username=postgres
password=mysecretpassword
parameter.db_name=postgres
```

When I run  mvn liquibase:update, there is an error:

```
[ERROR] Change Set src/main/resources/db/changelog/changelog-1-1-create-group-role-tenant-access.xml::create_tenant_access_group_role::failed.  
Error: ERROR: syntax error at or near "$"
```

Could you let me know what could be wrong?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you need to have your properties in `property` file, then it should be `parameter.db_name=postgres`, not `parameters.db_name=postgres`.

**Or** you can try to move `properties` to `changelog` file, into `<property>` tag.
Here are the [liquibase docs](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changelog_parameters.html).

Here's the example from these docs.

```
<databaseChangeLog
        xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:ext="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-2.0.xsd
        http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-ext.xsd">

    <property name="clob.type" value="clob" dbms="oracle"/>
    <property name="clob.type" value="longtext" dbms="mysql"/>

    <changeSet id="1" author="joe">
         <createTable tableName="${table.name}">
             <column name="id" type="int"/>
             <column name="${column1.name}" type="${clob.type}"/>
             <column name="${column2.name}" type="int"/>
         </createTable>
    </changeSet>
</databaseChangeLog>
```

Comment: sorry, I wrote it wrong: in my liquibase.properties, I did have parameter.db_name=postgres, but somehow it does not work.

Comment: I do not know why, but if I specify in my application.properties: liquibase.parameters.db_name: postgres, this works. The drawback would be: the liquibase change logs will be executed only when you run(e.g., java -jar or mvn spring-boot:run) the application

Comment: @Yashu, Good to hear that it finally works. Liquibase is being run when you start your application. This is how it's supposed to be.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know why, but if I specify in my application.properties: liquibase.parameters.db_name: postgres, this works.

Answer (score 0):

using ' I think should help

```
 GRANT ALL ON DATABASE '${db_name}' TO tenant_access;
```